# Is it posible to automatic change password for a synology user everyday?

Tags: linux, ftp, synology

So my question is if its possible to change a password for a user/ftp user every day and save it or email it out.

We have an FTP public user that we want to have dynamic password change every day so every morning we can post the daily password on your forum to give out. Meaby a script that changes the password to something new and saves it clean text in a txt file, and then we can grab the password and post it?

We use Synology

Comment: Using FTP, from a security standpoint, is BAD. Equally bad, if not worse, is storing passwords in plaintext and/or e-mailing them. I don't know much about Synology appliances, but if at all possible, I'd suggest you start with using a more secure protocol for file transfer, like scp, SFTP, even NFSv4.

Comment: @schaiba They've said they're going to post the password on a forum, so I don't think they need to worry about emailing in plain text

Comment: So i made this up